# Expected value, variance, evaluating limits and probability of drawing a ball from the urn

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

In the urn there is one white ball. We do infinite sequence of experiences -- in each step we draw from the urn a ball, we return it into the urn and simultaneously we add black ball. So in the first step we draw white ball, in the second white or black with equal probability etc.

My problems:

$1.$ How to show that with probability $1$ the white ball will be drawn infinitely many times?

$2.$ How to evaluate $\mathbb{E}X_n$ and $Var X_n$, where $X_n$ is an amount of draws to the time of $n$ inclusive in which we have drawn the white ball?

$3.$ Show that the sequence $\{X_n/\log n\}_{n\geq1}$ converges in probability to $1$?

**My attempts**

$1.$ I have no idea how to do it exactly. I know that probability of drawing white ball in infinitely many experiences is

$P($*the white ball will be drawn in every experience*$)$=$1\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot \ldots$.
Anyway I do not see if it is needed here and how to obtain that the white ball will be drawn infinitely many times with probability $1$.

$2.$My idea was to use the recursion

$\mathbb{E}X_1=1\cdot1=1$,

$\mathbb{E}X_2=1\cdot1\cdot \frac{1}{2}+2\cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac12+1=\frac32$,

$\mathbb{E}X_3=1\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac23+2(1\cdot\frac12\cdot \frac23+1\cdot\frac12\cdot \frac13 )+3\cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac13=\frac13+1+\frac12=\frac{11}{6}$.

Is it a good approach? I do not know if I understood the idea correctly.

$3.$ I have no idea how to begin -- especially how to write $X_n$ down.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint for 3: Note that Variance of $X_n$ is equal to $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}(1-\frac{1}{k}) = H_n - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$. It would be helpful to know $\frac{\ln(n)}{H_n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $\mathbb P(|\frac{X_n}{H_n} - 1| > \varepsilon) = \mathbb P(|X_n - H_n| > \varepsilon H_n)$. Can you use some inequality that will help you (alongside with $\frac{X_n}{\ln(n)} = \frac{X_n}{H_n}\frac{H_n}{\ln(n)}$ ) end the proof?

Comment: @DominikKutek I really appreciate your hint. I have a problem with ending the proof. Did you have in mind Chebyshev's inequality?

Comment: Following heropup answer, $X_n = \sum_{k=1}^n W_k$. Now, since $W_k$ are independent, we get $Var(X_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n Var(W_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}(1-\frac{1}{k})$ (we used that variance of bernoulli with parameter $p$ is $p(1-p)$ ). Yes, Chebyshev, because then (since $H_n$ is expectation) you get $\mathbb P(|\frac{X_n}{H_n}-1| > \varepsilon) \le \frac{Var(X_n)}{\varepsilon^2 H_n^2}$. Can you conlude?

Comment: @DominikKutek I obtained such result $$\dfrac{\operatorname{Var}X_n}{\epsilon^2H_n^2}=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}(1-\frac{1}{k})}{\epsilon^2(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k})^2}=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n(1-\frac{1}{k})}{\epsilon^2\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}}=\dfrac{1}{\epsilon^2}\left(\frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}}-1\right).$$ I guess that $\frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}}$ should have limit $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But I have problem with showing that (assuming that it is true, because it's only my guessing).

Comment: Your division is wrong. It should be $\frac{Var(X_n)}{\varepsilon^2H_n^2} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2H_n^2} \cdot ( H_n-  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} ) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2 H_n} - \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2 H_n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \to 0$, since $ H_n$ diverges to infinity, $\varepsilon$ is a constant, and series with terms $ \frac{1}{k^2} $ is convergent

Comment: @DominikKutek thank you a lot. I thought that such division is kind of illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim that the white ball is drawn infinitely many times is equivalent to saying that there is no positive integer $N$ such that after $N$ draws, the white ball is never drawn again.  In other words, pick a number $N$ as large (but finite) as you please.  What is the probability that among draws $N+1, N+2, \ldots$, the white ball is never drawn again?  It is the product of the individual probabilities that a black ball is drawn at every subsequent draw; i.e., $$\frac{N}{N+1} \cdot \frac{N+1}{N+2} \cdot \frac{N+2}{N+3} \cdot \ldots = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{N+n-1}{N+n}.$$  And what is the limit of this infinite product?

If by $X_n$ you mean the number of times the white ball is drawn in $n$ tries, then your recursion idea is appropriate (but ultimately not necessary).  Let $$W_I \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p = 1/i)$$ be equal to $1$ if on draw $i$, the drawn ball is white, and $0$ if black.  Then $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n W_i$, and $$\operatorname{E}[X_n] = \operatorname{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} W_i + W_n\right] = \operatorname{E}[X_{n-1}] + \operatorname{E}[W_n] = \operatorname{E}[X_{n-1}] + \frac{1}{n}.$$  Therefore, $$\operatorname{E}[X_n] = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} = H_n,$$ the $n^{\rm th}$ harmonic number.

The variance is computed similarly, except we have to explicitly state that because the individual draws are independent, the variance of the sum equals the sum of the variances:  $$\operatorname{Var}[X_n] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{Var}[X_{n-1}] + \operatorname{Var}[W_n].$$

I leave the third part as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much. How from $\mathbb{E}X_n=\mathbb{E}X_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}$ we have that $\mathbb{E}X_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$?

Comment: @Novice You don't need to use recursion for this.  For example, $$\operatorname{E}[X_n] = \operatorname{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n W_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{E}[W_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i},$$ by linearity of expectation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have you got maybe any idea how to start with the third one?